Impact of spatial term with spatial categorical variable in model
I am trying to understand the behaviour of spatial models when the response varaible is has spatial correlation and I am modelling with a predictor that describes regions. The aim is to prove that region is a sigificant predictor.
I have a response varaible (y) that is has significant spatial autocorrelation (based on Moran's I Stasistic).  And I have a significant predictor (region) for 'y' that is a categorical variable but describes the region that 'y' was measured in (e.g. country). I have two other continuous predictors (a and b), which are also significant. I created two models:
GLM
y ~ region + a + b

GLS, with spatial term
y ~ region + a + b, spatial term = lat + long

In both cases 'region', 'a', and 'b' are significant, and the estimate values with errors are fairly similar.
Is this because region is doing a good value at capturing the spatial variation in 'y' and so the spatial term does not add much? What's going on? Which papers/books should I read to understand this better?
I want to prove that the 'region' is an important predictor for 'y', rather than removing spatial correlation.
